# Compare List to Map from a partial string value match

Tags: apex

I am trying to make a Utility method that takes a `List<Contact>` parameter and compares the `Contact.Email` it to a custom list of URLS. I need to know if the `Contact.Email` matches any URL in my list even though the URL string is not a complete domain; meaning instead of *domain.com* it would just be *domain*

Not sure how I would do this comparisson, but I know I'm suppose to avoid nested loops so I'm attempting something like this so far:

```
public static List<Contact> compareThisList (List<Contact> contact_list){
    List<Contact> return_list = new List<Contact>();
    Map<URL__c,Domains__c> domain_list = new Map<URL__c,Domains__c>([SELECT Id, URL__c FROM Domains__c]);

    for(Contact c : contact_list){
        //if c.Email.contains() a partial map to domain_list.anykey then add to return_list
        // Not sure how since Email would be name@domain.com but domain_list keys would just have domain
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use nested loops. However, you always want to avoid SOQL inside of for loops. Or nested For loops which can invoke governor limit functions. https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm . So if you iterate over your collection of Contacts and peform a contains() operation on the String you are probably safe.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably split this out into two methods and use upper/lower case to avoid regular expressions, though they are certainly a viable alternative.

```
public with sharing class ContactServices
{
    public Set<String> domains
    {
        get
        {
            if (domains == null)
            {
                domains = new Set<String>();
                for (Domains__c domain : [SELECT URL__c FROM Domains__c])
                {
                    domains.add(domain.URL__c);
                }
            }
            return domains;
        }
        private set;
    }

    public List<Contact> matchesAnyDomain(List<Contact> candidates)
    {
        List<Contact> matches = new List<Contact>();
        for (Contact candidate : candidates)
        {
            if (matchesAnyDomain(candidate))
                matches.add(candidate);
        }
        return matches;
    }
    public Boolean matchesAnyDomain(Contact candidate)
    {
        for (String domain : domains)
        {
            if (candidate.Email.containsIgnoreCase(domain)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: So this response doesn't include my SOQL statement which I need because I'm not storing domain list in the class. And although this approach is interesting re-factoring the method like that, it is still a loop within a loop technically. @CoryCowgill commented that it might not be a big deal as my question suggest but is that to say then that there is no way to avoid that here?

Comment: You could incorporate that query into the `domains` property. The important part is that it is a `Set<String>` so you can check `contains`. I don't think you are going to avoid nested loops given your requirements, but your inner loop (over domains) is fairly limited, I would imagine.

Comment: note there is now a containsIgnorecase() method on String class

Comment: Good to know. Of course it is not in the documentation and since I could not remember offhand, I did not include it.

Comment: but it is in the doc - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index.htm

Comment: Not for String Methods http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm